# Best practice when sorting an array in pure javascript, if I have to send one group to the back

Tags: javascript

If I have the following array:

```
[0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```

And I'd like to sort it ascending order, barring zeros which I need on the end:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Bear in mind I don't have access to underscore or linq.js for this solution.
My current solution works, but feels quite heavy, long, and not very elegant. Here's my code:

```
        function sortNumbers(numbers) {
        var zeroNumbers = [];
        var notZeroNumbers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] === 0) {
                zeroNumbers.push(numbers[i]);
            } else {
                notZeroNumbers.push(numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        var sortedNumbers = notZeroNumbers.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
        });

        for (var x = 0; x < zeroNumbers.length; x++) {
            sortedNumbers.push(zeroNumbers[x]);
        }

        return sortedNumbers;
    }
```

**Can I improve on this solution?**

Comment: As a tip for future work with arrays, you should check out array functions, like .map, .sort, .filter, etc.

Comment: [Here's](http://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html) a great article for sorting and [here's](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) a big-o cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative solution using `Array.sort`, `Array.splice` and `Array.push` functions:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2];
arr.sort();
while(arr[0] === 0) { arr.splice(0,1); arr.push(0); }

console.log(arr);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 14):

This is not related to this question, but I was searching for "pure sort javascript" and this is the first answer.

Because sort mutates the original array, the best practice when sorting an array is to clone it first.

```js
const sortedArray = [...array].sort(/* optional comparison function*/)
```

Comment: That was exactly my question, and this answer what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

simply try

```js
var output = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2].sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; //if a == 0 then it will be a falsey value and a will be assigned Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  b = b || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  return a - b;
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I love this answer, it's so clean and crisp to read. Unfortunately MAX_SAFE_INTEGER isn't supported on ie to my understanding, bit of a shame!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Why not use `Infinity` instead ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 9, 8, 7, 0];
arr.sort(function (left, right) {
       return left == right ? 0 : (left === 0 ? 1 : (left < right ? -1 : 1));
});
console.log(arr)
```

This will always put zeroes at the end regardless of the size of the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort for this, which takes a closure/callback.

```
var sortedArray = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2].sort(function(currentValue, nextValue) {
    if(currentValue === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return currentValue - nextValue;
    }
});
```